# Pointer to function with defined type

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have function declaration as `int StartSale(CTXNSession & txnsession)` where `CTXNSession` is a class.

I need to create pointer to this function.

I tried to achieve it like this:

```
int  (*pFct)(CTXNSession&);
```

But I got compilation error.

But if the argument was of a predefined type , there was no error.

Please assist

Comment: Show your code and the compilation error...

Comment: Error is in that line int (*pFct)(CTXNSession&);

syntax error before '&' token

Comment: @EngHeba what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of function pointer is correct. Perhaps you forgot to declare the class? Or maybe some other error.
This code compiles without errors:

```
class CTXNSession; // your class
int StartSale(CTXNSession & txnsession) {} // your function
int main() {
    int  (*pFct)(CTXNSession&); // function pointer declaration
    pFct = StartSale; // assignment for a bonus
    return 0;
}
```